# I am getting this error, Unable to find 'serverMethodName' on 'compound://c.componentName'. Failing descriptor: {markup://c:componentName}

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Oddly, it is working fine in Dev. The issue is found after deploying the code to UAT.

```
<!-- Component -->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="ID"/>
<aura:attribute name="hasEditPerm" type="boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:If isTrue="{!v.isSave}">
            <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.hasEditPerm}">
                <div class="slds-form-element-button">
                    <ui:button class="button" label="Edit" press="{!c.Edit}" />
                </div>
            </aura:renderIf>
</aura:If>
```

On init method,

```
doInit : function(cmp,evt,helper){
    var reocID1 = cmp.get("v.recordId");
    var action2 = cmp.get("c.userPermission");
    action2.setParams({"recordID":reocID1});
    action2.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state == "SUCCESS"){
            var canEdit = response.getReturnValue();
            cmp.set("v.hasEditPerm",canEdit);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action1);
}
```

On server side controller,

```
@AuraEnabled
public static boolean userPermission(Id recordID){
   UserRecordAccess  userRecordPermission = [SELECT RecordId, 
            HasEditAccess 
            FROM UserRecordAccess 
            WHERE UserId =: UserInfo.getUserId() 
            AND RecordId =: recordID 
            LIMIT 1];
    return userRecordPermission.HasEditAccess;
}
```

Did I make any silly mistake which is still not clear to my eyes?

Comment: Can you try `type="Id"` instead of `type="ID"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bunch of issues, and they're mostly stemming from a failure to observe proper capitalization. Rather than point all of them out, I'm simply going to correct the code. Pay *careful* attention to changes made. One note I will say is that `aura:renderIf` should not be used. Also, use `force:hasRecordId`, but do not define a `recordId` attribute.

```
<!-- Component -->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="hasEditPerm" type="Boolean" default="{!true}"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.isSave, v.hasEditPerm)}">
  <div class="slds-form-element-button">
    <ui:button class="button" label="Edit" press="{!c.Edit}" />
  </div>
</aura:if>
```

Comment: My problem was resolved after a re-deployment but thank you @sfdcfox for your answer and pointing out the casual mistakes we make during coding and also for optimizing my code.